# Medi-Cal eligibility for parent

Tags: united-states, income-tax, california, medicare

If I claim my mother as a dependent will that affect her eligibility for Medi-Cal? She lives with me and I pay all of the expenses.

Comment: Status as dependent doesn't seem to be one of the criteria at https://www.dhcs.ca.gov/services/medi-cal/Pages/DoYouQualifyForMedi-Cal.aspx ... But I'm not sure how the family income calculation would work in that case.

Comment: You can only claim her as a dependent if her annual income is below $4700 or so. Is her income below that?